# Experiment to determine the center of mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, geometry, experimental-technique, experimental-technology

Consider an axially symmetric rigid body with asymmetric mass distribution. Generally, the center of mass (and therefore moments of inertia) can be determined by knowing the center of mass of the consituent components of the of the body. However this data may not always be available.

> Is there an experiment which can determine the center of mass of an axially symmetric rigid body with asymmetric mass distribution in the absence apriori knowledge of the component masses and their individual centers of mass?

---

*Edit*

Please provide any new ideas or insights on extending the ideas towards center of mass determination to determination of (at least some) moments of inertia.

Comment: Just find the point at which you can balance it on a wedge (for example)? It should balance at the centre of mass...

Comment: @Philip For a $\text{3D}$ object that's not good enough. Unless someone beats me to it, I'll answer this tomorrow.

Comment: @Philip indeed wedge balancing and hanging the body from three distinct pivot points to observe the plane on which the center of mass lies (downward plumb line method) are candiates. However, it is not possible to conduct a wedge balancing (the body has irregular surfaces) or plumb line (this one is more feasible although the body is heavy and does not have strong fixtures to enable hanging from a pivot) experiment for this object.

Comment: @Gert Hm yeah, you're right, I spoke too soon. The question brought back memories of my experiments with a [Kater's Pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kater%27s_pendulum), which is an axially symmetric rigid body with an asymmetric mass distribution, but it's also quite thin, so balancing it would work. But a more general shape is not so obvious, you're both right!

Comment: @Gert thanks for the comment. I am an engineer and I tried to come up with some experiments but have not been able to figure out experiments other than those using the usual ideas (wedge balancing or plumb line). Please let me know if you have any thoughts about an experiment to find the moments of inertia (atleast some). The body type is symmetric about one axis and is akin to half a cylinder (axially sliced through a diameter).

Comment: @kb314 These ideas are correct.

Comment: Hm. I would be very surprised (and interested!) if there was a method that didn't involve wedges or plumb lines... One impractical and naive method would actually be to mark points on the object and throw it, in order to find that point on it that moves along a parabola without rotation. Of course, you'd have to do this along each of the axes of the object. I've done it with cardboard, and it's been quite successful, but it's clearly not practical! :)

Comment: @Philip the object most certainly cannot be thrown. However, it can be hung onto a rigid pole (akin to a monkey hanging onto a pole) and rolled about it (axial, lateral or vertical translation and pitching or yawing rotation are restricted). Further, the pole can be replaced by a rope and the object can then move laterally and vertically (but not longitudinally) besides rolling, pitching and yawing.

Comment: If you had a way of spinning the object in order to determine the principle axes then you could find these axes and they all pass through the CoM, somewhat related to how wheels are balanced. A bit involved and you'd need to keep track of any wobbling in the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hang the object from a point, the center of mass will hang directly below the point. This gives you a line that contains the center of mass.

If you do that using two or three different points, you have 2 or 3 lines that all pass through the center of mass. Find where the lines intersect.

You can also hang the object from two points. The center of mass will hang directly below the line connecting the points. That gives you a plane containing the center of mass.

---

*Edit*

If the body is difficult to hang or balance, *put it on a table with three or more legs and place a scale under each leg.* From the distance and weights, you can infer the point under the center of mass.

Rotate the object and repeat. You can find two or three planes containing the center of mass.

If the object is easy to slide, you can avoid calculation. Slide it until the weight under each leg is the same.

Comment: indeed wedge balancing and hanging the body from three distinct pivot points to observe the plane on which the center of mass lies (downward plumb line method) are candiates. However, it is not possible to conduct a wedge balancing (the body has irregular surfaces) or plumb line (this one is more feasible although the body is heavy and does not have strong fixtures to enable hanging from a pivot) experiment for this object.

Comment: The idea in the edit (I have made cosmetic edits to the edit for clarity) is interesting and applicable in the case of the body I am considering. Thanks! Please do let me know if you have any further insight or ideas.