# How to know the position of an object when calculating the center of mass, without using integrals?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, symmetry, integration

For example, if I have a 1/4 piece of pizza, what is the position?

Comment: Use symmetry if you can. E.G. it would be along the line that bisects the piece of pizza. Or [Experiment to determine the center of mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/620965/37364)

Answer (score 1):

Try to balance the 1/4 piece of pizza with one finger.

Comment: it's an exercise